# How to clear data after logout

Tags: javascript, logout, hawtio

I do use hawtio 1.5.5 for my website. I have an issue with user's credentials. User's name and password are stored in browser. When user performs logout, I would like to be this data wiped. I did some investigation, and there is called method doLogout() in index.html file (hawtio-web). I know these credentials are stored in localStorage but I don't know, which is the right spot to wipe them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution. You have to inject service into your plugin

```
module.run(..., preLogoutTasks) {
   // your code
   preLogoutTasks.addTask("clearCredentials", () => {
       localStorage.removeItem('userName');
       localStorage.removeItem('password');
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to username and password being stored in browser instead of the localStorage cache for security reason, you need to use the browser feature to clean up the browser cache. You should be able to clear the cache by restarting the browser or use private browsing like Incognito.

Comment: Chm, i do not think so. The credentials are stored in localStorage. I just need some construction to trigger wiping of these.